# Problems with jQuery selector (after append)

Tags: jquery

I have seen 1 or two posts like this problem, but mine differs slightly, and the proposed fixes didn't work for me (usually a typo for them) In my case it is not a typo.

I am appending into a div with `jQuery`, creating a div inside of it on loadup.

When this div is clicked it launches into a method.

However, the selector will not work.

Here is the place where I append the data:

```
else if (isEquipped != true && data.archer.level == 0) {
    $("#locked-list").append(`
        <div id="archer-locked" class="archer-link"></div>
    `);
}
```

Here is the selector:

```
$("#archer-locked").on("click", e => {
  console.log("hmmm");
  if (e.target.className != "") {
    classView(e, false);
  }
});
```

Everything looks like it should inside the inspect console.

However, it is not triggering for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for a click on the parent, then check against the child:

```
$("#locked-list").on("click", "#archer-locked", e => {...});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! IS there an explanation why this works and not the other way??

Comment: @William Because when your code ran, `$("#archer-locked").on("click", e => {...})` was run immediately, and as there was no element that matched `#archer-locked`, jQuery discarded the listener.

Comment: Ohhh! Okay, I thought those things were dynamic and it would pick up on when there was a valid selector. Thanks again!

Comment: Nope - you need to attach the listener to the parent (as long as the parent is not dynamic) and then listen for a click on the dynamic element.

Comment: @William if my answer fixed your problem, please consider marking it as accepted.